# SQL Include zero rows in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a derived a table with a category, subcategory, date, time, and value columns (from a much larger table).

The dates are all dates with a particular property (sometimes last 5 weeks, sometimes last 5 Sundays, sometimes month to day), as with the times (sometimes midnight to now every hour, sometimes last 30 minutes every 2 minutes).

The category and subcategory are uninteresting, but if they have no entry in the value field for the time parameters they're completely ignored (which is fine).

When there is no value which matches the combination of the other columns, the row is completely ignored.

My problem is that I need the 0's included.  Is there some way I can fill in 0's to the rest of the table?

My thought was to do a cross join of the table against itself using only the first 4 columns, then left join with isnull() on the value column.  But the cross join kept including the 5th column.

Comment: Can you post some sample input and output

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow:  "they're completely ignored (which is fine)" versus "My problem is that I need the 0's included".  Which is it?  Included or ignored?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all combinations of `date`, `time`, `category`, and `subcategory` that your query returns.  If so, you can use `cross join` to get the combinations and then `left outer join` to fill in the values or `0`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select d.date, ti.time, sc.category, sc.subcategory, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct time from t) ti cross join
     (select distinct category, subcategory from t) sc left outer join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.time = ti.time and
        t.category = sc.category and t.subcategory = sc.subcategory;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try that out, and fill in more details when I can.

Comment: It works, but it takes about a minute.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the same functionality without the time issue.

Comment: @user38858 . . . If you can put your query into a temporary table or table variable, that will probably speed the query.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  When I crossed the time stuff with the category stuff, it would always take forever; until I put the category stuff in a temp table.

I have no idea why, but it seems to work.

Comment: @user38858 . . . You could try building three indexes on the table, one for `date`, one for `time`, and one for `category, subcategory` for performance.